# How to deal with $interval is not a function error in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs $interval function to increase/decrease a value continuously when I click on up/down arrows. But I am getting an error "TypeError: $interval is not a function" when I try to increase/decrease. How to solve this problem, thanks in advance. This is the code I have written so far:

```js
$scope.onMouseDown = function (type) {
  promise = $interval(function () {
    if (type == 'Inc') {
       $scope.increaseVal();
    }
    else if (type == 'Dec') {
       $scope.decreaseVal();
    }
  }, 150);
};
$scope.stopInterval = function () {
   $interval.cancel(promise);
};
```

```html
<div><a href="javascript:;" class="arrow" data-spin="up"><i class="fa fa-caret-up" ng-mousedown="onMouseDown('Inc')" ng-mouseup="stopInterval()" ng-mouseleave="stopInterval()" ng-click="increaseVal()"></i></a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="arrow" data-spin="down"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" ng-mousedown="onMouseDown('Dec')"
ng-mouseup="stopInterval()" ng-mouseleave="stopInterval()" ng-click="decreaseVal()"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: have you included $interval in the controller dependencies?

Comment: Even reading documentation would answer your question.

Comment: read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval . there are examples as well about the usage

Comment: What do you `increaseVal` and `decreaseVal` functions look like? @dev8080 Wouldn't it say cannot read property cancel of undefined if that was the case?

Answer (score 2):

Inject the $interval service into your controller:

```
angular.module('yourmodulename').controller('yourcontrollername', [
    '$scope', '$interval',
    function ($scope, $interval) {
       $scope.onMouseDown = function (type) {
           promise = $interval(function () {
               if (type == 'Inc') {
                   $scope.increaseVal();
               }
               else if (type == 'Dec') {
                   $scope.decreaseVal();
               }
           }, 150);
       };
       $scope.stopInterval = function () {
           $interval.cancel(promise);
       };
}]);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it say `cannot read property cancel of undefined` if that was the case?

Comment: What line is the error being thrown?  I'm guessing it's where you are trying to set the promise variable, in which case you are using $interval as a function.  You aren't even getting to the code where you are trying to call cancel on the $interval service.

Comment: Thank you guys, actually I am calling this function from multiple ways. I missed the injection of $interval from one calling function. Now it is working fine. Apologies for troubling you all.